# Bessel function only particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I have a heterogeneous modified Bessel equation:
$$z'' +\frac{1}{r}z'-v^2z=G(r),$$

I find the homogeneous solution of it:
$$y_h=u_1 I_0 (νr)+u_2 K_0 (νr)$$

and a particular solution via Variation of Parameters:
$$y_p=∫[G(r) K_0 (νr)rdr]  I_0 (νr)-∫[G(r) I_0 (νr)rdr]K_0 (νr)$$
but with my Boundary condition:
$$y(r→∞)=0  $$
$$ y^{'}(r=0)=0  $$
$$ y^{''} (r→∞)=0$$
i get for both constant in homogeneous solution zero. Another quastions what i use for integral boundaries in particular solution $$K_0(0)→∞$$

Comment: I am guessing that in your equation $v$ means $\nu$. What do we know about $G$?

Comment: G is some function of r